# How to include a razor DropDownList selected value as one of the parameters of its javascript onchange event

Tags: javascript, razor, onchange

Firstly I am not sure that I have written the code for putting a javascript onChange event in my razor DropDownList correctly so please be merciful to me and help if there is an issue.The question I have is how can I add the selected value of the DropDownList as one of the js onChange parameters.

On a regular html select list I can simply write:

```
<select type="text" name="Doc" onchange="event(this.value)">
```

My code looks like this currently:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DocumentListID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "form.doOCR("+ this.value + ");" })
```

The parameter where I have written `this.value` which doesn't work. How can I do this?

**I will have to put an edit under here because I have recieved a good answer however my code is a bit more complicated and I don't think a separate event handler will work in this case. Please see the additional information**

In fact the `@Html.DropDownList` is within a foreach loop and includes additional parameters for each item in my model. So what I had in mind was that I need an answer which allows me to have an event handler on the object itself. Here is more code:

```
@foreach (var claimfile in Model)
{

    @Html.DropDownList("DocumentListID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "form.doClaimFileOCR(" + claimfile.ClaimFileID + ", " + Value + ");" })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create event handler separately like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DocumentListID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class =    "form-control")

<script>
      $("#DocumentListID").change(function(){
         alert($(this).val();
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Please see my new edit. There is more information which i think shows that a separate event handler will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured it out:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DocumentListID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "form.doOCR("+ this + ");" })
```

I just pass `event(this)`

in the event function you can get the value like `$(obj).val()`